# error: incompatible types when passing an array to another method

Tags: java, arrays, incompatibletypeerror

I apologize if my code is messy, as I am very new to Java and have also been editing out parts of my code to see if I can make it work. I have an assignment in which I have to generate `100` random integers in between `0` and `25` and store them in an array. Then, I have to create another method that sorts out the even integers into a separate array, then do this with the odds in another method.

My problem is, no matter how hard I try, I cannot manage to get my even sorting method to recognize the original array with the `100` random integers. The command prompt says it requires `int[]` but found int. I even tried making the sortEvens method require an integer instead of an array and the prompt said the exact opposite. Here is my code:

```
public class AssignmentEight
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    final int NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 100;
    int numbers[];
    int evens[];
    int odds[];
    numbers = new int[100];

    for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++)
    {
        numbers[n] = (int)(Math.random() * 25);
    }

    evens = sortEvens (numbers);
    display (evens);
}

public static int sortEvens (int a[])
{

    int evens[];
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    {
        int x = (a[n] % 2);
        if (x == 0)
        {
            evens[n] = a[n];
        }
    }
    return evens;
}

public static void display (int array[])
{
    for (int n = 0; n < array.length; n++)
        System.out.print(array[n]);
        System.out.print("\t");
}
}
```

I apologize if this doesn't make sense. My main problem is that I cannot compile my program. I will try to provide further details if necessary.

Comment: May not be relevant now, but `evens[]` isn't initialized so when it does compile, you'll receive a `NullPointerException` when `evens[n] = a[n]` gets executed.

Comment: Since this is an assignment, we leave to you the next problem: how to return only the even numbers? BTW I suggest you rename sortEvens to selectEvens, or getEvens, because a sort generally means changing the order of the data so that it is in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sortEvens()` method needs to return an `int[]`. You've also forgotten to initialize your array.

```
public static int[] sortEvens (int a[]) {
    int evens[] = new int[100];
    // ...
}
```

In `getEvens()` method

```
if ((x == 0)) // ^ (x == 2)) <-- remove this ^ condition
    totalEvens += 1;

for (n = 0; n < a.length; n++) { // loop a.length times; not totalEvens
    x = (a[n] % 2);
    if (x == 0) { // ADDED
        evens[y] = a[n];
        y++; // increment only when an even is found
    } // ADDED
}
```

In `getOdds()` method

```
for (n = 0; n < a.length; n++) { // loop a.length times; not totalOdds
    x = (a[n] % 2);
    if (x == 1) { // ADDED
        odds[y] = a[n];
        y++; // increment only when an odd is found
    } // ADDED
}
```

Comment: Since this is an assignment, we leave to you the next problem: how to return *only* the even numbers? BTW is suggest you rename `sortEvens` to `selectEvens`, or `getEvens`, because a `sort` generally means changing the order of the data so that it is in ascending order.

Comment: @andy256, I think you should direct this comment at OP; not me.

Comment: @user2709168 Since this is an assignment, we leave to you the next problem: how to return only the even numbers? BTW I suggest you rename sortEvens to selectEvens, or getEvens, because a sort generally means changing the order of the data so that it is in ascending order. (Thanks Ravi).

Comment: @andy256, if you want to communicate something to OP you should add the comment on the question itself. You add a comment on an answer only when you want to convey something to the user who posted the answer. The exception to this is when you want to direct the comment towards someone who has already left a comment on that answer in which case you use @ username. I hope you see my point here.

Comment: I did what you and @andy256 said. My new code is at [link](http://pastebin.com/SKnAQUy6). I think I'm closer, as it definitely shows the integers it generated, but I can't stop it from replacing every odd integer in the even array with a zero and vice versa. What do you think?

Comment: @user2709168 Found the problem. Updated my answer.